# Exact same code repeated multiple times for different data types; Any way to make one function that can handle all possible types?

Tags: c#, function, types

I'm trying to optimize some code that was written by somebody else. In one section, it has a lot of repeated code; there are four 'if' statements, and inside one, after the first line is the exact same code. The reason for all the different 'if' statements is that depending on the type of page the user is on, the data is deserialized differently; however, after the data is deserialized, it is used exactly the same each time.

```
if (smartFormId == EktronSmartForms.StandardPage)
{
    var pageData = (EkXml.Deserialize(typeof(StandardPage), ContentData.Html) as StandardPage);
    var sections = pageData.LeftContent.AdditionalSection;
    title = pageData.LeftContent.ParentBreadcrumbTitle;

    if (sections != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in sections)
        {
            tempLD = new LinkData();
            tempLD.Text = item.SectionTitle;
            tempLD.Class = "class=\"sub-parent\"";
            autoData.Add(tempLD);

            if (item.Link != null && item.Link.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var child in item.Link)
                {
                    tempLD = new LinkData();
                    tempLD.Text = child.a.OuterXML;
                    tempLD.Link = child.a.href;
                    tempLD.Class = "class=\"\"";
                    autoData.Add(tempLD);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
else if (smartFormId == EktronSmartForms.DoctorPage)
{
    var pageData =
        (EkXml.Deserialize(typeof(DoctorProfilePage), ContentData.Html) as DoctorProfilePage);
    var sections = pageData.LeftContent.AdditionalSection;
    title = pageData.LeftContent.ParentBreadcrumbTitle;

    if (sections != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in sections)
        {
            tempLD = new LinkData();
            tempLD.Text = item.SectionTitle;
            tempLD.Class = "class=\"sub-parent\"";
            autoData.Add(tempLD);

            if (item.Link != null && item.Link.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (var child in item.Link)
                {
                    tempLD = new LinkData
                    {
                        Text = child.a.OuterXML,
                        Link = child.a.href,
                        Class = "class=\"\""
                    };
                    autoData.Add(tempLD);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else if (smartFormId == EktronSmartForms.StoryPage)
{
    var pageData = (EkXml.Deserialize(typeof(StoryPage), ContentData.Html) as StoryPage);
    var sections = pageData.LeftContent.AdditionalSection;
    title = pageData.LeftContent.ParentBreadcrumbTitle;

    if (sections != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in sections)
        {
            tempLD = new LinkData();
            tempLD.Text = item.SectionTitle;
            tempLD.Class = "class=\"sub-parent\"";
            autoData.Add(tempLD);

            if (item.Link != null && item.Link.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (var child in item.Link)
                {
                    tempLD = new LinkData
                    {
                        Text = child.a.OuterXML,
                        Link = child.a.href,
                        Class = "class=\"\""
                    };
                    autoData.Add(tempLD);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else if (smartFormId == EktronSmartForms.MaintainedPage)
{
    var pageData =
        (EkXml.Deserialize(typeof(MaintainedPage), ContentData.Html) as MaintainedPage);
    var sections = pageData.LeftContent.AdditionalSection;
    title = pageData.LeftContent.ParentBreadcrumbTitle;

    if (sections != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in sections)
        {
            tempLD = new LinkData();
            tempLD.Text = item.SectionTitle;
            tempLD.Class = "class=\"sub-parent\"";
            autoData.Add(tempLD);

            if (item.Link != null && item.Link.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (var child in item.Link)
                {
                    tempLD = new LinkData
                    {
                        Text = child.a.OuterXML,
                        Link = child.a.href,
                        Class = "class=\"\""
                    };
                    autoData.Add(tempLD);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, because of how pageData is created, it has a different type for each if statement; in the first it's StandardPage and sections is StandardPageLeftContentAdditionalSections; in the second pageData is DoctorPage and sections is DoctorPageLeftContentAdditionalSections; etc...

I'd like to make one function where I can transfer all the repeated code, and just call that function inside each 'if' statement (or better, at the end of all the 'if' statements) but (1) I can't declare pageData and sections before the if statements, because if I declare

```
var sections = new StandardPageLeftContentAdditionalSections();
```

I'll get a conversion error if I try to do

```
pageData = (EkXml.Deserialize(typeof(DoctorProfilePage), ContentData.Html) as DoctorProfilePage);
sections = pageData.LeftContent.AdditionalSection;
```

What I would like to do is this:

```
var sections = ????
if (smartFormId == EktronSmartForms.StandardPage){
    var pageData = (EkXml.Deserialize(typeof(StandardPage), ContentData.Html) as StandardPage);
    sections = pageData.LeftContent.AdditionalSection;
}
else if (smartFormId == EktronSmartForms.DoctorPage)
{
    var pageData =
        (EkXml.Deserialize(typeof(DoctorProfilePage), ContentData.Html) as DoctorProfilePage);
    sections = pageData.LeftContent.AdditionalSection;
}
etc...

autoData = ProcessSections(type??? sections, List<LinkData> autoData);

________________________________________________________________________________

private List<Link> ProcessSections(type??? sections, List<LinkData> autoData){
    if (sections != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in sections)
        {
            tempLD = new LinkData();
            tempLD.Text = item.SectionTitle;
            tempLD.Class = "class=\"sub-parent\"";
            autoData.Add(tempLD);

            if (item.Link != null && item.Link.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (var child in item.Link)
                {
                    tempLD = new LinkData
                    {
                        Text = child.a.OuterXML,
                        Link = child.a.href,
                        Class = "class=\"\""
                    };
                    autoData.Add(tempLD);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return autoData;
}
```

Is there any way that I can simplify this, given the problem of sections being a different data type every time?

Comment: yes you could if you use generics and/or an interface.

Comment: Use both generics and interface.

Comment: I understand the concept, but I'm not sure how to implement that. Could you give me an example of how to make my code generic/use an interface?

Comment: See [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use an interface:

```
public interface IPageData{
    object LeftContent{get;} //Use the correct return type rather than 'object' here
}
```

Then when you declare your page types make sure you implement the interface:

```
public class StandardPage:IPageData {
    ...
}
public class DoctorPage:IPageData{
    ...
}
```

Then you can deserialise into a common object:

```
IPageData pageData;
switch(smartFormId) {
    case EktronSmartForms.StandardPage:
        pageData = (EkXml.Deserialize(typeof(StandardPage), ContentData.Html) as StandardPage);
        break;
    ...
}

var sections = pageData.LeftContent.AdditionalSection;
title = pageData.LeftContent.ParentBreadcrumbTitle;

if (sections != null)
{
    foreach (var item in sections)
    {
        tempLD = new LinkData();
        tempLD.Text = item.SectionTitle;
        tempLD.Class = "class=\"sub-parent\"";
        autoData.Add(tempLD);

        if (item.Link != null && item.Link.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var child in item.Link)
            {
                tempLD = new LinkData();
                tempLD.Text = child.a.OuterXML;
                tempLD.Link = child.a.href;
                tempLD.Class = "class=\"\"";
                autoData.Add(tempLD);
            }
        }
    }
}
```